# how to auto complete files names on bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tabs

I have a bash shell script that `cd` to directory according to a variable. After that I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and files don't appear like in terminal. Ex:

```
#!bin/bash
clear
mypath=/opt/projects/
cd $mypath
echo "Enter tour file:"
read n
echo $n
```

on `read` code ups, the files don't appear when I press tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` command requires the `-e` flag in order to use the `readline` library to edit the command line (including completions):

```
echo "Enter tour file: "
read -e n
echo "$n"
```